# How to build for netcore50

Tags: c#, .net-core, project.json

I want to build a console app, which uses Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client .
However it seems, that SignalR.Client is not available on nuget for netcoreapp1.1 :

```
Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client 2.2.1 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1). Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client 2.2.1 supports:
  - net40 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.0)
  - net45 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5)
  - netcore50 (.NETCore,Version=v5.0)
  - portable-net45+sl5+win8+wp8+wpa81(.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile344)
  - portable-win81+wpa81 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile32)
One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1.
```

I would like to make my app as open/portable as possible (I don't distribute compiled binaries, only source to be used by other folks).
How can I make below project.json changed, so I could compile and run the app (probably with netcore50) :

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "debugType": "portable",
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client": "*"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.1": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.1.0"
        }
      },
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance .

Answer (score 0):

You can use netcore50 in .net core app 1.1 like below. Updated project.json-

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "debugType": "portable",
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {

    "Newtonsoft.Json": "*",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client": "2.2.1"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.1": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.1.0"
        }
      },
      "imports": "netcore50"
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: It works, thank you ! 
Now I need to read somewhere, what is the differences between netcore50 and dnxcore50 and what is the impact of such change.

Comment: @wx78 both are obsolete names. In the future Microsoft should use .NET Standard names.